# How do I send an email from a non-gmail account using the appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

I have successfully sent an email using the Google App Engine. However the only email address I can get to work is the gmail address I have listed as the admin of the site. I'm running the app on my own domain (bought and maintained using Google Apps). I would like to send the email from my own domain. Here's the code (or something similar to it):

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

sender = "myaddress@google.com"
sender_i_want = "myaddress@mygoogleapp.com"

mail.send_mail(sender=sender,
    to="Albert Johnson <Albert.Johnson@example.com>",
    subject="Your account has been approved",
    body=some_string_variable)
```

And the error I get when I try to send it from my own domain is "InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender". I own the domain, I do in fact authorize using my domain to send the mail, I just need to know how to convince the App Engine that this is true.

Comment: As per will's instructions I added the other email as an admin and it worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a restriction of [App Engine's mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail.html):

> The sender address can be either the email address of a registered administrator for the application, or the email address of the current signed-in user (the user making the request that is sending the message).

If you've got Google Apps running on that domain, you should have (or be able to create) an @thatdomain.com email addresses that you can register as an administrator of the App Engine app in question, which will then let you send email "from" that address.

Comment: Are some people also using third party e-mail services to fill this need?

Comment: Any email from any provider will do, only restriction is being a developer/admin of the appengine account.